# I am getting error while running image for my project. Here i am trying to dockerize my application

Tags: python, mysql, docker, pyramid

```
db_url = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
  raise KeyError(key)
  KeyError: 'OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL'

My Dockerfile look like:
 FROM python:2.7.13
 RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libsasl2-dev python-dev 
 libldap2-dev
 RUN apt-get install -y gcc libc-dev unixodbc-dev libffi-dev
 RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils
 RUN apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev libssl-dev netcat
 RUN pip install --upgrade pip
 COPY . /LAE-python
 WORKDIR /LAE-python
 RUN pwd
 #RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 RUN python setup.py develop
 ENTRYPOINT ["pserve"]
 CMD ["development.ini","--reload"]


My Code :
import os
import sys
import transaction
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column,Integer, String,ForeignKey

from mtools.settings import mysql_user,mysql_passowrd,database_name

db_session = 
scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,autoflush=False))
db_url = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL']
engine_string = db_url+database_name
```

I am getting error for "db_url = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL']" line, My problem is how to set all these env variable in one dockerfile so that i can build image and run it. Eariler code in LAE server now we are moving to some containerize based server .

Comment: Hm .. so, you are looking for recipes on how to 'set env variable in dockerfile'. Is there anything specific you did not understand from the top results for that search term on basically any search engine?

Comment: See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env

Comment: @shmee, Do i need to pullmysql image as well in my docker file?

Comment: Unless you plan on running the DB in the same container, or need access to mysql-common/mysql-client from that container: no. As long as your local Python installation comes with all the required 3rd-party packages (and your `setup.py develop` seems to accomplish that, otherwise I would have expected an import error first) you should be set for a pure Python client container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is related to a ENV configuration setting, so, I've removed everything else to show you where the problem is:

This is the dockerfile with the ENV setting

```
FROM python:2.7.13
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libsasl2-dev python-dev libldap2-dev
RUN apt-get install -y gcc libc-dev unixodbc-dev libffi-dev
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev libssl-dev netcat
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

ENV OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL "your URL"

COPY . /LAE-python
WORKDIR /LAE-python

CMD ["python","-u", "setup.py"]
```

This is setup.py:

```
import os
import sys

db_url = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL']
print db_url
```

Now you can access your os.environ variable.

Reference:

https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/